# Mount a secret in a Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, secret-key

As the title says, im trying to mount a secret, as a volume, into a deployment.

I found out i can do it in this way if `kind: Pod` but couldnt replicate it on  `kind: Deployment`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

volumeMounts:
     - name: certs-vol
       mountPath: "/certs"
       readOnly: true
volumes:
      - name: certs-vol
        secret:
        secretName: certs-secret
```

the error shows as follows `ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.volumes[1]): unknown field "secretName" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Volume, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.volumes[2]`

is there a way to do this, exclusivelly on deployment?

Comment: Does `secretName:` need to be indented one step further (a child of `secret:`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) mentioned in the comment:

> Does  `secretName:`  need to be indented one step further (a child of  `secret:`)?

Your yaml file should be as follow:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

volumeMounts:
     - name: certs-vol
       mountPath: "/certs"
       readOnly: true
volumes:
      - name: certs-vol
        secret:
          secretName: certs-secret
```

You can read more about [mounting secret as a file](https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/secrets-management-in-kubernetes-378cbf8171d0). This could be the most interesing part:

> It is possible to create  `Secret`  and pass it as a  **file**  or multiple  **files**  to  `Pods`.
> I've created a simple example for you to illustrate how it works. Below you can see a sample  `Secret`  manifest file and  `Deployment`  that uses this Secret:
> **NOTE:**  I used  `subPath`  with  `Secrets`  and it works as expected.

```
apiVersion: v1  
kind: Secret  
metadata:  
  name: my-secret  
data:  
  secret.file1: |  
    c2VjcmV0RmlsZTEK  
  secret.file2: |  
    c2VjcmV0RmlsZTIK  

---  

apiVersion: apps/v1  
kind: Deployment  
metadata:  
...  
    spec:  
      containers:  
      - image: nginx  
        name: nginx  
        volumeMounts:  
        - name: secrets-files  
          mountPath: "/mnt/secret.file1"  # "secret.file1" file will be created in "/mnt" directory  
          subPath: secret.file1  
        - name: secrets-files  
          mountPath: "/mnt/secret.file2"  # "secret.file2" file will be created in "/mnt" directory  
          subPath: secret.file2  
      volumes:  
        - name: secrets-files  
          secret:  
            secretName: my-secret # name of the Secret
```

> **Note:**  `Secret`  should be created before  `Deployment`.

Comment: i was a little burned out, thanks it worked like a charm